# Send time from html form to php

Tags: forms, time

I have a form, that saves date of birth in the database. This form passes three variables to php: $ayear $amonth $adate
Now I need to save these in the database in a format: 00/00/0000 (or 00/00/00, if 00/00/0000 is not supported).
I need to create a date() variable, but I dont know how. All the examles on the internet use time() or now() which are not usefull in my case. Can someone give me the right function?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL you'll want to save as `YYYY-MM-DD` with the field type set to date. I'd save this variables value to the database.

```
$birthday = implode('-', array($year, $month, $day));
```

Comment: yes, I'm using MySql and Date datatype. So, I dont need to create fancy date elements... just save as a string? Cool. Thx

Comment: There's nothing fancy about it at all. It's just a different field type. This way gives you the most flexibility and readability. All my code does it create a string like `1984-12-17`.